# Tenant to tenant user migration in Azure Active Directory using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to migrate users using the MS Graph API in Azure AD?

If so, please explain how to migrate users from one tenant to the other using the MS Graph API.

Comment: Seems there is not possibilties to migrate users from one tenan to another tenant using MS Graph API but can be possible with office 365 tool . Please follow this document to for more information : https://www.softwarepro.org/blog/migrate-office-365-users-from-one-tenant-to-another-tenant/

Answer (score 0):

You can export the users with MS Graph. Note, you can't export the passwords. This means that you have to create a new password and share it with the users. Or choose a random password and let the users reset their password using the self-service password rest feature.

Here is an example how to export the users from a directly

```
       public static async Task ListUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting list of users...");
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            Dictionary<string, string> usersCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            int page = 0;

            try
            {
                // Get all users
                var users = await graphClient.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Select(e => new
                    {
                        e.DisplayName,
                        e.Id
                    }).OrderBy("DisplayName")
                    .GetAsync();

                // Iterate over all the users in the directory
                var pageIterator = PageIterator<User>
                    .CreatePageIterator(
                        graphClient,
                        users,
                        // Callback executed for each user in the collection
                        (user) =>
                        {
                            usersCollection.Add(user.DisplayName, user.Id);

                            return true;
                        },
                        // Used to configure subsequent page requests
                        (req) =>
                        {
                            var d = DateTime.Now - startTime;
                            Console.WriteLine($"{string.Format(TIME_FORMAT, d.Days, d.Hours, d.Minutes, d.Seconds)} users: {usersCollection.Count}");

                            // Set a variable to the Documents path.
                            string filePrefix = "0";
                            if (usersCollection.Count >= 1000000)
                            {
                                filePrefix = usersCollection.Count.ToString()[0].ToString();
                            }

                            page++;

                            if (page >= 50)
                            {
                                page = 0;
                                string docPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), $"users_{filePrefix}.json");
                                System.IO.File.WriteAllTextAsync(docPath, JsonSerializer.Serialize(usersCollection));
                            }

                            Thread.Sleep(200);

                            return req;
                        }
                    );

                await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

                // Write last page
                string docPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), $"users_all.json");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllTextAsync(docPath, JsonSerializer.Serialize(usersCollection));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

After you export the users, you can import them back to the other tenant. The following example creates test users. Change the code to set the values from the files you exported earlier. Also, this code uses batch with 20 users in single operation.

```
public static async Task CreateTestUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient, AppSettings appSettings, bool addMissingUsers)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter the from value: ");
            int from = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);

            Console.Write("Enter the to value: ");
            int to = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);
            int count = 0;


            Console.WriteLine("Starting create test users operation...");
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            Dictionary<string, string> existingUsers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // Add the missing users
            if (addMissingUsers)
            {
                // Set a variable to the Documents path.
                string docPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "users.json");

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(docPath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Can't find the '{docPath}' file.");
                }

                string usersFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(docPath);

                existingUsers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(usersFile);

                if (existingUsers == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Can't deserialize users");
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"There are {existingUsers.Count} in the directory");
            }

            List<User> users = new List<User>();

            // The batch object
            var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

            for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
            {
                // 1,000,000
                string ID = TEST_USER_PREFIX + i.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0');

                if (addMissingUsers)
                {
                    if (existingUsers.ContainsKey(ID))
                        continue;
                }

                count++;

                try
                {
                    var user = new User
                    {
                        DisplayName = ID,
                        JobTitle = ID.Substring(ID.Length - 1),
                        Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>()
                    {
                        new ObjectIdentity
                        {
                            SignInType = "userName",
                            Issuer = appSettings.TenantName,
                            IssuerAssignedId = ID
                        },
                        new ObjectIdentity
                        {
                            SignInType = "emailAddress",
                            Issuer = appSettings.TenantName,
                            IssuerAssignedId = $"{ID}@{TEST_USER_SUFFIX}"
                        }
                    },
                        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                        {
                            Password = "1",
                            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
                        },
                        PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword"
                    };

                    users.Add(user);

                    if (addMissingUsers)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Adding missing {ID} user");
                    }

                    // POST requests are handled a bit differently
                    // The SDK request builders generate GET requests, so
                    // you must get the HttpRequestMessage and convert to a POST
                    var jsonEvent = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeAsJsonContent(user);

                    HttpRequestMessage addUserRequest = graphClient.Users.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
                    addUserRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                    addUserRequest.Content = jsonEvent;

                    if (batchRequestContent.BatchRequestSteps.Count >= BATCH_SIZE)
                    {
                        var d = DateTime.Now - startTime;
                        Console.WriteLine($"{string.Format(TIME_FORMAT, d.Days, d.Hours, d.Minutes, d.Seconds)}, count: {count}, user: {ID}");

                        // Run sent the batch requests
                        var returnedResponse = await graphClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

                        // Dispose the HTTP request and empty the batch collection
                        foreach (var step in batchRequestContent.BatchRequestSteps) ((BatchRequestStep)step.Value).Request.Dispose();
                        batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
                    }

                    // Add the event to the batch operations
                    batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(addUserRequest);

                    // Console.WriteLine($"User '{user.DisplayName}' successfully created.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```